# Display: flex; no longer resizes my box if the box is put inside another div

Tags: css, flexbox, display

I'm using display:flex so that my boxes are lined up nicely and resize to the window. When I put my headers into another div they continue to be lined up correctly, but no longer resize to my smaller window. Why is this? How can I work around this, since I want to keep that function.

Here is my code:

`

```
<div class="flexbox-container-row">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="box">
                        Reflektion
                    </h3>
                </div>
               
                <div>
                    <h3 class="box">
                        Tips & Trix
                    </h3>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h3 class="box">
                        Information
                    </h3>
                </div>
               
</div>
```

`

I tried making another div to hold a column under each header, but when I created the div to hold the new flexbox column the div removed the resizing function of the box around the header.

Comment: What CSS is in use here?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the css you have done so far. :)